# sorting numbers using hadoop mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

The data looks like this, first field is a number,
11
20
11
78
20

And I want to sort these lines according to the first field numerically , which means after sorting it should look like this,
11
11
20
20
78

but hadoop giving like this:
11
20
78

Comment: I guess your reducer has some bug (not handle the case that the values has same key). Could you paste your codes?

Comment: Try posting your code if you'd like answerers to help more concretely.

Answer (score 1):

The same key is handled by the same reducer. So, 11 and 11 are handled by the same reducer. If you output the key of this reducer, then 11 is output only once. The same goes for 20.
If you just want to output 11 11 20 20 78, then do the following:

```
reduce(key, iterator values) {
    int counter = 0;
    while (values.hasNext()) {
        counter++;
        values.next();
    }
    for (int i =0; i < counter; ++i) {
        output.collect(key, <whatever>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not iterating over the results. The reducer output  will be a key and a `list` of values. To show all the values for a key you need to iterate over the list.

```
public void reducer(Text key ,Iterable<IntWritable> value, Context context) throws IOexception, InterruptedException{
    for(IntWritable number: value){
        context.write(key,number);
    }
}
```